# Displaying Text in a Label in Powershell Script

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-forms-designer

I have a GUI for a powershell script. The GUI contains a Result label. I would like to use this label to display the success or failure of each command in my script. 2 examples are below. However when the second command runs, it removes the first line in the Results label. Anyway to force it to add another line until script completes? Or a better way to do this?

```
function RunScript{

##Enable Remote Desktop
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server" -Name "fdenyTSConnections" -Value 0
                Enable-NetFirewallRule -DisplayGroup "Remote Desktop"
                $resultsLabel.text = "Enabling Remote Desktop"




 #Sets optical disk drive letter to 'O:'
                Set-WmiInstance -InputObject( Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_volume -Filter "DriveLetter = '$OpticalDiskLetter'") `
                -Arguments @{DriveLetter='O:'} 
                $resultsLabel.Text = "Setting optical drive letter to 'O:'..."



}
```

Comment: Why don't you use the environment variable `$?`? This will show you if the previous command succeeded or failed with a boolean.

Comment: Sorry, can you provide a little more detail or example?? Thanks,

Comment: The environment variable `$?` is similar to the batch environment variable `%ERRORLEVEL%` and its value changes depending on if the previous command succeeded where its value would be `true` if it succeeded and `false` if it didn't. The `%ERRORLEVEL%` variable takes its values as numbers having certain numbers for certain errors and 0 for successes (unless the command manipulates the error level like `choice`). So in powershell you can use `<command you want to execute>; $?` to see if the previous command succeeded.

Comment: Say if I ran `Write-Host "Test"; $?` it would print Test then print the variable `$?` which would be true if the previous succeeded or false if it failed. You could also use the `||` or `&&` operators which run commands if the previous command succeeded or not as well.

Comment: To learn more about those operators try checking out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators?view=powershell-7

Answer (score 0):

```
$resultsLabel.Text += "`nSetting optical drive letter to 'O:'..."
```